Work employment visa refusal for Malta
The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable. What could be done to correct this? Can I still use the Approval of Principle letter to apply for new visa after I was refused? It's still valid till December. Or I should go for new application with identity Malta?

What is the question? You get a refusal and a reason. Check what was missing or what could be misinterpreted. And be aware of scammers who try to sell "jobs".

Exactly what kind of work-related residence permit did you apply for? What documentation did you provide? Did you check the relevant check list? What kind of job did you have an offer for? Is the employer real?

Please edit your question to add that info as well as the other info requested.

Can I still use the Approval of Principle letter to apply for new visa after I was refused? That sounds like a bad idea. Isn't this letter precisely about the purpose and conditions of the intended stay? It didn't seem to satisfy the authorities.

What is an approval of principle letter and who issued it?

The approval in principle letter was issued by identita Malta. It's an approval given to the employer to go ahead and employ the applicant.

@GODWINUZU Are you still hoping to work for the same company? The visa refusal suggests that the Maltese authorities do not trust that you will. What new documentation will you be able to provide to change the outcome? The Approval of Principle letter seems like a bit of a red herring, given the reason why the visa was refused, it sounds like there might be more fundamental problems with your plan.

Yes, I am still interested in working with the company. The company gave me two contract letters, one for 3 months starting from December 2023 and then 6 months starting from May 2024. The approval of principle letter was issued on 10th May. So I suppose to submit the 6 months, instead 3 months later was submitted. I believe that was where the mistake was. I don't know if I will go ahead and apply for fresh visa or ask the company to start fresh application for approval in principle letter from identita Malta. The current approval in principle letter still valid till December 10, 2024. What

I can forward the documents to you privately if you want so that you can help me check and find out where I made a mistake before applying for new visa.
